# Using SnapEngage with Emberjs cause a JS error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, yahoo

As soon as I add:

```
<script src="/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js"></script>
```

on the same page where there's our snagengage chat code:

```
<!-- begin SnapEngage code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var se = document.createElement('script'); se.type = 'text/javascript'; se.async = true;
        se.src = '//commondatastorage.googleapis.com/code.snapengage.com/js/4f645e9b-afb9-4226-9ebc-f8fc52d28cef.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(se, s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- end SnapEngage code -->
```

it provokes an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined 4f645e9b-afb9-4226-9ebc-f8fc52d28cef.js:223
YAHOO.register 4f645e9b-afb9-4226-9ebc-f8fc52d28cef.js:223
(anonymous function) 4f645e9b-afb9-4226-9ebc-f8fc52d28cef.js:242
```

[image]

Anyone ever experienced this? Any suggestion about how to fix this?

PS: I tried removing that JS line and it works, that's definitively a conflict between Ember and some YAHOO library I guess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket on this with SnapEngage and they recently pushed out a fix.  If you had a SnapEngage account prior to Mar 6, 2014, then you need to click "Save" within the "Style" section of your account in order for the JS to be updated to the latest version.  After this, the error should go away - worked for me!

NOTE: I am using Ember 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I think it was caused by a _super() on the YAHOO.register function cycling through line 233 twice. The first time it does it the variables k.versions and k.builds are defined, but the second time they are not (perhaps because the super reruns the YAHOO.register function without passing in any arguments. Regardless of exactly what caused it, I was able to remedy the issue (albeit in a VERY hacky way) by making the following edits to the snapengage.js source:

1) On line 233 change:

```
k.versions.push(p);k.builds.push(q);
```

to:

```
k.versions ? k.versions.push(p):false;k.builds ? k.builds.push(q):false;
```

All this does is check to see if the variables are defined and if they are, push to them. If not, do nothing.

I placed the edited snapengage.js source file in app/assets/javascripts/vendor/ and then added the following line to my application.js file:

```
//= stub ./vendor/snapengage.js
```

This will stop your ember application from loading the SnapEngage source when the app loads.

Finally, I wrote a chat mixin and loaded the snapengage.js script as follows:

```
App.Chat = Em.Mixin.create({
  agentOnline: false,

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._getChatApi();
  },

  _getChatApi: function() {
    var url = 'assets/home/vendor/snapengage.js',
        _this = this;

    $.getScript(url).done(function() {

        // Your custom SnapEngage Javascript API code here. For example...
        SnapEngage.getAgentStatusAsync(function(online) {
            _this.set('agentOnline', online);
        });

    });
  },

});

App.IndexView = Em.View.extend(Home.Chat, {
    // The rest of your view code here
});
```

The snapengage.js script won't load itself twice but if you're using the mixin on multiple pages you might want to make sure you're not loading the chat assets (images, loading spinner, etc) twice because the plugin seems to make a call to snapengage.com everytime you click on the 'help' button rendered on the webpage.

As I mentioned, it's a very hacky solution and I don't recommend editing the source code for plugins, but this will give you a fix to easily use Snapengage in an Ember.js app.